# Which surface do these conditions determine (and how to visualize it)?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, surfaces

I'm interested in visualising the following surface of points $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3$ which satisfy the following equation and inequalities:

$$ \begin{cases}
  x + y + z = 0\\
  x \leq y \leq z
\end{cases} $$

The first equation determines a plane passing through the origin $(0,0,0)$, therefore the inequalities (which I have written in compact form) should determine a section of this plane. Another way would be to start from the part of space determined by $x<y<z$ and then see the intersection with the plane, but I can't manage to visualize it and I can't seem to get it to appear on 3D online graphing tools.

One thing that I thought might help is to project it to the $yz$ plane with the substitution $x = -y-z$, where the surface reduces to an angle delimited by $z=y$ and $z=-2y$:

$$ \begin{cases}
  z + 2y \geq 0\\
  z - y \leq 0 
\end{cases} $$

However, now I don't know how to incorporate this figure in 3D with the additional constraint $x=-y-z$. Is it like a "slice" of 3D space with a slant?

Beyond this, I am also interested in the more general $n$-dimensional problem with $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)\in\mathbb{R}^n$ such that:

$$ \begin{cases}
  x_1 + \ldots + x_n = 0\\
  x_1 \leq x_2 \leq \ldots \leq x_n
\end{cases} $$

So some intuition for these higher dimensional cases would also be useful. Any help?

Comment: A thought: The region determined by $x \leq y \leq z$ is the intersection of two half-spaces, where $x \leq y$ and where $y \leq z$, and each of _these_ is bounded by a plane. Find the lines of intersection of each plane with $x + y  + z = 0$ (or vectors spanning these lines), and sketch from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Establish an orthonormal coordinate system on the plane $x + y + z = 0$. Two orthonormal vectors on it is $\frac1{\sqrt 2}(0, -1, 1)$ and $\frac 1{\sqrt 6}(-2,1,1)$. An arbitrary point $(x,y,z)$ on the plane should be some linear combination $au + bv$. Or
$$x = -\frac2{\sqrt6}b\\y =-\frac a{\sqrt 2} +\frac b{\sqrt 6}\\z =\frac a{\sqrt 2} + \frac b{\sqrt 6}$$
The inequalities then become $$y \ge x \iff -\frac a{\sqrt 2} +\frac b{\sqrt 6} \ge -\frac2{\sqrt6}b \iff b \ge \frac a{\sqrt 3}\\
z \ge y \iff \frac a{\sqrt 2} + \frac b{\sqrt 6} \ge -\frac a{\sqrt 2} +\frac b{\sqrt 6} \iff a \ge 0$$

Which is the region between the positive $b$-axis, and the positive ray of the line $b = \frac a{\sqrt 3}$, which is at an angle of $60^\circ$ with the positive $b$-axis. So your region is  a $60^\circ$ angle in the plane and its interior.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense. Would you be able to comment on the higher dimensional case as well? Specifically, in the 4D case, I would imagine now that, projecting on the $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=0$ hyperplane, the figure is delimited by three lines, like an infinite triangular prism, is that right? So the actual figure is just "at an angle" in 4D space.

Comment: In $n$ dimensions, the hyperplane (call it $H$) has $n-1$ dimensions. Thus one needs to identify an $n-1$ dimensional coordinate system $\{y_i\}$ in it. Each inequalily $x_k \le x_{k+1}$ separates on the hyperplane $x_k = x_{k+1}$ which intersects $H$ in a hyperplane of dimension $n-2$. When $n=4$, $H$ is a 3-dimensional space, and the the dividing surfaces in it have dimension $2$, so they are planes, not lines. The figure will be a sold-angle with three planar sides.

Comment: In fact, because each side mimics the $n=3$ case in the post, the sides will have $60^\circ$ angles. Which means the figure will be a regular tetrahedron with one of its faces removed and the figure extending to $\infty$ in that direction.